# BroadcastReceiver not receiving Intent in the same Composable in Android

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, broadcastreceiver

I’m having a little experiment on android API 26 using Jetpack Compose and I’m having trouble with sending and receiving broadcasts within the same composable.
Here's the code for my receiver:

```
class ImpReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.i("Implicit Broadcast", intent.extras?.getString("message") ?: "None")
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the registration:

```
    val context = LocalContext.current

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        val receiver = ImpReceiver()

        context.registerReceiver(
            receiver,
            IntentFilter("example.ImpBroadcast"),
            RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
        )

        Log.i("Receiver", "Implicit receiver registered")

        onDispose {
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
            Log.i("Receiver", "Implicit receiver disposed")
        }
    }
```

And here's the code for sending the broadcast:

```
Intent()
    .apply {
        action = "example.ImpBroadcast"
        putExtra("message", "Implicit receiver called!")
    }
    .let { context.sendBroadcast(it) }
```

The problem is, when I use RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag while registering the receiver, I don’t receive the broadcast (i.e., I don’t get the log). However, when I change the flag to RECEIVER_EXPORTED, it works as expected. This is confusing because both pieces of code are in the same composable and should be running in the same context.

I have been searching for a while but still can't find anything useful. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated.